# Jquery show/hide divs

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

Having a html structure like this:

```
<div id="newest">
    <nav>
        <ul id="newNav">
            <li><a href="#">Dani's Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alex's Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul class="dani">
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <ul class="alex">
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Dani's Photos** corresponds to **ul class="dani"** and Alex's photos to **ul class="alex"**. What I need is to show only 1 ul at the time, and show/hide the other when click on the links inside , and showing by default the first ul.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried adapting this to my needs: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/ but didn't managed to make it work as I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
<div id="newest">
    <nav>
        <ul id="newNav">
            <li><a href="#" data-target="dani">Dani's Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-target="alex">Alex's Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul class="dani">
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <ul class="alex">
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $('#newNav a').click(function(){
      var selected = $(this).data('target');
      $('#newest > ul').hide().filter('.' + selected).show();
    }).first().click();
});
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zkPcb/

Comment: magnifico :). Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

Amend your HTML like this:

```
<div id="newest">
    <nav>
        <ul id="newNav">
            <li><a href="#dani">Dani's Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#alex">Alex's Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul id="dani" class="photos">
        <li>....Dani....</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="alex" class="photos">
        <li>....Alex....</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
        <li>........</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$("#newNav A").on("click", function() {
    $(".photos").hide();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $(target).show();
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RNNpR/1/)**

Comment: this looks great, trying and will let you know the results

Comment: +1 That's exactly the way I would have done it, and it makes the most sense semantically.

Comment: thanks, but I have decided to use @Gaby aka G. Petrioli's version

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
     $(".alex").hide();
});
$("#dan").click(function()
{
   $(".alex").hide();
   $(".dani").show();

});
$("#alex").click(function()
{
    $(".dani").hide();
    $(".alex").show();
});
```

Here is the sample : http://jsfiddle.net/yFDUB/4/

**EDIT :** As per your comment, you need a generic solution which works for n number of uls
I wrapped the uls in a div with id "divItems" and i am assuming that the class name of the divs and the id of the links will be same.

```
$(function(){

    $("#divItems ul").hide();
    $("#divItems ul:first").show();
});

$("#newNav a").click(function()
{
  $("#divItems ul").hide();
  var className=$(this).attr("id"); 
  var objToShow=    $("."+className);  
  objToShow.fadeIn();  

});
```

Here is the sample : http://jsfiddle.net/yFDUB/10/

Comment: thanks you, but the problem with this is that the ul will have much much more than alex and dani, and I was hopping for a more "automated" way.

Comment: thank you very much but I have decided to use @Gaby aka G. Petrioli version